# Submitting Fabric/Yarn Craft Items to be Judged

Tags: crocheting, knitting

What should be done when delivering items to a fair or similar for judging?

I have a ~15" doily I want to submit, but I don't know if they want it in an envelope, sack, or nothing. It's sandwiched between two cake boards right now.

I could also mount it, but I'm not sure I want to go to the trouble, since I was planning on using it, not displaying it, after the fair.

The instructions I have offer no help nor means of contact (in fact, the website to submit to was incorrect on their documents this year). My searches return submission details for other places, but even those documents are lacking.

If anyone has some experience, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no appropriate site for the question you're asking.

Comment: @walrus Any chance you might have an answer, though? ^_^;

Comment: Sorry, but even if I did know an answer (I know almost nothing about knitting), it's bad form to answer off-topic questions because it just encourages people to ask more of them...

Comment: Yeah... seems like you would want to ask the people putting the fair together.

Comment: If you rephrased your question to be about mounting lace doilies for show in general it would be better, and it looks like someone answered it in that context.

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with this medium, but I would use the packaging problem/opportunity to present your work in the highest possible style.  Instead of sandwiching it between cake boards, consider using a sheet of acrylic for the top bread and thin wood, stained to a shade which compliments your yarn as the bottom bread.

If you have a makerspace ( or library with a laser cutter) near you, you can buy the acrylic sheet and plywood from a hardware store (or amazon) and then cut it to the shape and size you need.  You could also drill small holes in the corners of each "slice of bread" and fasten it all together with yarn, using bow knots which can be easily untied by the judges for closer inspection of your work.

Comment: It's a bit too delicate for that. As I mentioned I _can_ mount it (on felt), which I may end up doing.

The cake boards are just to keep the dust off and retain its shape from when I finished it. I didn't make it for competition...I just made it and realized I was within the deadline to submit to the fair this year ^_^